# Any difference between ~ and $HOME?

Tags: macos, command-line

It would appear that ~ and $HOME are equivalent in command line and shell scripts. Is that true?

Answer (score 14):

It's true to a certain extent.

- `$HOME` is an expression for expansion of the environment variable `HOME`
- `~` (tilde) is a separate shell expansion component
  <sup>see footnote</sup>

When used as a command argument and in separation from other strings, `$HOME` and `~` are usually equivalent.

But there are cases where they differ:

- if the string containing either is quoted, for example:

  ```
  # echo "My home directory is $HOME"
  My home directory is /Users/techraf
  # echo "My home directory is ~"
  My home directory is ~
  ```
- if they are concatenated to a string, for example:

  - `dd if=${HOME}/source_file of=${HOME}/destination_file` will work.

    Shell will pass arguments `if=/Users/techraf/source_file` and `of=/Users/techraf/destination_file` containing a valid path to the `dd` command.
  - `dd if=~/source_file of=~/destination_file` won't work

    Shell will pass arguments `if=~/source_file` and `of=~/destination_file` to the `dd` command and it will report an error as it does not interpret `~`.

---

<sub>footnote:</sub>

In fact `~` is by default replaced with the value of `HOME`, but if `HOME` is empty, it is resolved to a home directory:

```
# echo $HOME
/Users/techraf
# export HOME=/dummy
# echo $HOME
/dummy
# echo ~
/dummy
```

```
# unset HOME
# echo $HOME

# echo ~
/Users/techraf
```

From `man bash`:

> Tilde Expansion
>
> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), all of the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or all  characters,  if  there  is  no unquoted  slash)  are  considered a tilde-prefix.  If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login name.  If this login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the value of the shell parameter HOME.
>
> If  HOME  is  unset,  the  home  directory of the user executing the shell is substituted instead.  Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory associated with the specified login name.

Comment: I've removed the comments, please use https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat or a private chat for extended discussions.

Comment: As a side note: If you `unset HOME` in other shells, such as `ksh, zsh, or dash` then `echo ~` will not expand to the path of your home folder.

Comment: @fd0 `ksh` behaviour seems funny - it resolves just to the username when no `HOME` is defined.

Comment: POSIX states- If the login name is null (that is, the tilde-prefix contains only the tilde), the tilde-prefix is replaced by the value of the variable HOME. If HOME is unset, the results are unspecified. Since the HOME variable is changeable, there are advantages to using something like- `cd ~username`. In a script  `cd ~"$(id -un)"` will take you to the user's home folder no matter what HOME is set to.

Comment: There is a more nasty special case. If you run a LaunchDaemon (so, it's root) I saw that $HOME is empty but ~ is /var/root (as makes sense). So in some scripts I make sure to set it myself, which is very annoying

Answer (score 0):

`$HOME` is available on login early stages when `~` is not available. The reason is that `$HOME` is defined by system environment, and `~` is a shell shortcut. That's why `$HOME` is preferred for shell scripting.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail in which moment does shell resolve the environment variable using parameter expansion (`$parameter`) syntax (quote: "*login early stages*", so that it is "*preferred for shell scripting*"), but not yet `~`?